# AddYear does not work when day value is <10

Tags: vb.net

I'm having problems with the following: I have 2 textboxes masked to `ShortDate`. When I insert a date into the 1st textbox I need the 2nd textbox to display a date 2 years later.

For example, if I put 10/08/2013 the 2nd box should show 10/08/2014.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub txtAcquired_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAcquired.LostFocus
    Dim Acquired As Date
    Acquired = txtAcquired.Text
    txtDisposal.Text = Acquired.AddYears(2)
End Sub
```

It works fine when the day value of the date is > 9 but when I put a date with day value between 1 and 9 it does not work, e.g. if I put 04/04/2011 the 2nd box shows 40/42/013_.

If someone can help on this problem that will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try converting types before working with them. `Date` does not = `String`.

Comment: Please put Option Strict On at the top of your code or set it in your project's properties.  You are assigning a string to a Date variable in your sample.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fault with the date returned. This fixes it.

```
Private Sub txtAcquired_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAcquired.LostFocus
    Dim Acquired As Date
    If Date.TryParse(txtAcquired.Text, Acquired) Then
      txtDisposal.Text = Acquired.AddYears(2).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    End If
End Sub
```